# In Java, how to keep the original window's focus, despite of clicking JFrame

Tags: java, macos, window, focus

I've some trouble in using this `setFocusableWindowState(false)` method in java:

`JFrame frame = new JFrame();
 frame.setFocusableWindowState(false);
 frame.setVisibled(true);`

Even in Windows OS, it works definitely well.
That is - when `JFrame` is visible, it keeps the focus of original window.
So I could send some events such as `Keypress` to original window.

But, I'm still failing in Mac with same code.
Just it lost his focus, however original window (showing before new `JFrame` window appears) lost also its focus. So I never can send any event to that window in Mac.

Please help me to keep the original window's focus in Mac OS X, though new `JFrame` appeared.
Additionally, I used the method `setAlwaysOnTop(true)` in same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I found the way to implement this in Mac.

Actually, the window lost its focus when user click the `JFrame` by mouse left button.

But when clicked by mouse right button, it never lost original focus. (I found this accidentally.)

So, using JNI, I hooked all mouse events and then consume mouse left button click event. At the same time generated mouse right button click event in code.

I hope you will get something from this answer.
Best regards.

Comment: Hi, can you please tell me who to solve this without JNI?

Answer (score 1):

can you try this

```
 frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.NORMAL);
 frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
 frame.requestFocus();
 frame.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
```